# Reset value or set to default selected option jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to reset the value of closest select option.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.limitation_points').hide();
    $('.field .limitSelected').each(function () {
        $(this).change(function () {
            var selected = $(this).val();
            if (selected == '1') {
                $(this).closest('.field').find('.limitation_points').fadeIn(200);
            } else {
                $(this).closest('.field').find('.limitation_points').fadeOut(200);
                $(this).closest('.field').find('input[name="pillers[]"]').val("");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field">
    <input id="limitation1" type="radio" class="limitSelected" name="limitation" value="1" />Yes
    <input id="limitation2" type="radio" class="limitSelected" name="limitation" value="0" />No       
    <select id="pijlers" class="pillers" name="pillers[]">
        <option class="placeholder" selected disabled>Make Choice</option>
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Till fadeIn fadeOut my code is working how it should. But This code does't reset the value of select options when value has "0".

Can anyone help me with this, what i am doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Using "-1" as default value and also using *select* instead of *input* as your selector, should do the trick.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.limitation_points').hide();
    $('.field .limitSelected').each(function () {
        $(this).change(function () {
            var selected = $(this).val();
            if (selected == '1') {
                $(this).closest('.field').find('.limitation_points').fadeIn(200);
            } else {
                $(this).closest('.field').find('.limitation_points').fadeOut(200);
                $(this).closest('.field').find('select[name="pillers[]"]').val("-1");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field">
    <input id="limitation1" type="radio" class="limitSelected" name="limitation" value="1" />Yes
    <input id="limitation2" type="radio" class="limitSelected" name="limitation" value="0" />No       
    <select id="pijlers" class="pillers" name="pillers[]">
        <option class="placeholder" value="-1" selected disabled>Make Choice</option>
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `value` attribute to the default `<option>` and remove `disabled`.

When you use the empty string reset there is no matching option for it

```
<option value="" class="placeholder" >Make Choice</option>
```